# Preventing onChange event firing whilst updating selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anyone can provide advice here. Using MVC ASP.NET. I have a htmlhelper ddl

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ddlStartTime, new SelectList(Model.StartTimes, "Text", "Value", ViewBag.selected), new { data_test = "true", @Class = "form-control", onchange = "SubmitDayViewer(this.id)" })
```

Then I have a AJAX json request which goes and gets my data and returns a partial view along with some other json string data.

```
    function SubmitDayViewer(pId) {
        var obj1 = { dateValue: $('#dteTester').val(), timeValue: $('#ddlStartTime').val(), callerID: pId };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("_ADayRoomViewerPartial", "Common")',
            data: obj1,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                  $("#ddlStartTime").select2("val", data.DDLTimeValue);
            }
        });
}
```

The problem I can't overcome is preventing the @Html.DropDownListFor onChange event firing once I change the selected value. So I end up in an infinite loop. I need to devise a way to only fire the event when user changes the actual ddl. manually not when other controls on the page update and as a consequence need to change the selected value dynamically without firing the event. So basically fire onChange on some occasions not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the change event with `off`, then re-add it with `on`:-

```
function SubmitDayViewer() {
        var obj1 = { dateValue: $('#dteTester').val(), timeValue: $('#ddlStartTime').val(), callerID: this.id};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("_ADayRoomViewerPartial", "Common")',
            data: obj1,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                  $("#ddlStartTime").off('change', SubmitDayViewer);
                  $("#ddlStartTime").select2("val", data.DDLTimeValue);
                  $("#ddlStartTime").on('change', SubmitDayViewer);
            }
        });
}
```

also, use `this` within the function instead of passing it in.

**Edit**

If this still happens, then the select2 must be delaying the set somehow. So you could look into the plugin code to see whats going on, or you could add a timeout to re-add the change event.

```
$("#ddlStartTime").off('change', SubmitDayViewer);
$("#ddlStartTime").select2("val", data.DDLTimeValue);
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $("#ddlStartTime").on('change', SubmitDayViewer);
}, 2000); // 2 seconds
```

personally I would look in the plugin to find a cleaner solution.